# Merge string in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
let data = ['week1_aopCrop', 'week1_actCrop', 'week2_aopCrop', 'week2_actCrop']
```

the output should be:

```
['week1', 'week2']
```

anyone can help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as

```js
let data = ["week1_aopCrop", "week1_actCrop", "week2_aopCrop", "week2_actCrop"];

const result = [...data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.add(curr.split("_")[0]);
    return acc;
  }, new Set()),
];

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here as:

```js
let data = ["week1_aopCrop", "week1_actCrop", "week2_aopCrop", "week2_actCrop"];

const result = [...new Set(data.map((s) => s.split("_")[0]))];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let data = ['week1_aopCrop', 'week1_actCrop', 'week2_aopCrop', 'week2_actCrop'];
let out = [];
data.forEach((item,index)=>{
    if(!out.includes(item.split("_")[0])) {
    out.push(item.split("_")[0]);
  }
});
console.log(out);
```